# Is it a bad practice to use the bind() method for many elements?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, event-handling, bind

Assuming there are many popups (like more than 30) in my page, and I need to make them listen to a click event handler. Below is Example 1 in the jQuery syntax:

```js
$('.popup').on('click', function () {
    // do something
});
```

I have learned a suggestion in the past that the Example 1 approach is bad for performance/memory (I can't recall the exact reason) because each element listens to an independent anonymous function. And the suggestion said that it is better to name the event handler and then make all the elements listen to the named event handler, like the following Example 2:

```js
function clickEventHandler() {
    // do something
}

$('.popup').on('click', clickEventHandler);
```

Now, for each popup, I need to pass a variable which is specific to the popup, into the named event handler. The approach I think of is using the [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) mehtod like the following Example 3:

```js
function clickEventHandler(someInfo) {
    // do something
}

$('.popup').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', clickEventHandler.bind(null, $(this).attr('data-some-info')));  
});
```

However, it concerns me that the description of the `.bind()` method says:

> The `bind()` method creates a new function...

My question is: What does "creates a new function" mean exactly? Does it mean creating an independent anonymous function every time the method is used and is as bad as Example 1 when it comes to performance/memory?

Comment: You got bad information. It's using the same anonymous function for all the elements.

Comment: "Creates a new function" means it creates a new closure that contains the original function body and a new environment containing the parameter bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1 is just fine - you're only creating a single function, and passing it to every event handler.

Now, if you had something like

```
$('.popup').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function () {
    // do something
  });
});
```

*that* would indeed be very slightly wasteful, because you'd be creating a new callback function for every iteration in the loop.

But

> Assuming there are many popups (like more than 30) in my page

30 is absolutely nothing with modern hardware. Now, if you had a thousand, or ten thousand, then there might be something to consider, maybe.

> My question is: What does "creates a new function" mean exactly? Does it mean creating an independent anonymous function every time the method is used and is as bad as Example 1 when it comes to performance/memory?

Example 1 is just fine - but calling `.bind` in a loop is somewhat similar to my snippet above, in which there are many separate functions in memory.

To achieve what you want:

1. Use event delegation (optional - this way you only attach a single listener to a parent, instead of a
   listener to every single element)
2. Check the attribute inside the handler instead of outside it

```
function handleClick(e) {
    const someInfo = this.dataset.someInfo;
    // rest of function
}

$(document.body).on('click', '.popup', handleClick);
```

Comment: He doesn't need to use event delegation to avoid creating multiple functions.

Comment: Yeah, it's not necessary, but if there were *tons and tons* of elements, it might be slightly helpful.

Comment: There will be multiple event listeners, but not multiple functions.